# Grouped categories not showing correctly on wordpress website

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to recreate the grouped categories chart in Highcharts using the Blacklabel plugin. 
I have the scripts stored on my own website's server. Unfortunately, the chart doesn't render correctly and I am not sure why. 
[example grouped-categories chart](https://csg.lshtm.ac.uk/local-charts/)

Original Jfiddle using the blacklabel plugin for grouped categories:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/

Here is a Jfiddle with my code and scripts (which are not working)
https://jsfiddle.net/5m2eabt3/

Looking at the code it seems I can't use the original code:

```
$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

Because my scripts are stored on my own server, I have to use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Many thanks for taking the time to read this thread!

Comment: Hi @AdrianD, it seems that the problem is related to wordpress. Highcharts charts work regardless to the use of `addEventListener` code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8rtvkajf/

Comment: Are you sure that the path and permissions are right?

Comment: Thank you both for replying. The path and permissions are the same for both scripts: `<script src="//httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/highcharts/code/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/highcharts/grouped_categories-master/grouped-categories.js"></script>`      Do they have to be in the same folder? The chart is being rendered but not grouped .see [link](https://csg.lshtm.ac.uk/local-charts/)